# How can DAYOFWEEK() in Snowflake return values from 0 to 7?

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

There are only 7 days in the week, so the values could go from 0 to 6, or from 1 to 7. Yet the Snowflake docs say that `DAYOFWEEK()` can return values from 0 to 7. Is this right?

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/year#usage-notes

[image]

(question received by DM, sharing here in case more people are wondering)

Answer (score 2):

The secret is in the [1] note in the docs: "Results dictated by the values set for the WEEK_OF_YEAR_POLICY and/or WEEK_START session parameters".

Let's try this out:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET WEEK_START = 7;

SELECT 
       '2016-01-02T23:39:20.123-07:00'::TIMESTAMP AS tstamp,
       DAYOFWEEK(tstamp) AS "DAY OF WEEK",
       DAYOFWEEKISO(tstamp) AS "DAY OF WEEK ISO"
       ;

-- TSTAMP   DAY OF WEEK DAY OF WEEK ISO
-- 2016-01-02 23:39:20.123  7   6

ALTER SESSION SET WEEK_START = 0;

SELECT 
       '2016-01-03T23:39:20.123-07:00'::TIMESTAMP AS tstamp,
       DAYOFWEEK(tstamp) AS "DAY OF WEEK",
       DAYOFWEEKISO(tstamp) AS "DAY OF WEEK ISO"
       ;

-- TSTAMP   DAY OF WEEK DAY OF WEEK ISO
-- 2016-01-03 23:39:20.123  0   7
```

This shows how depending on the session configuration of `WEEK_START`, values could go from 0 to 6, or from 1 to 7 for `DAYOFWEEK`.